# Populating a treeview recursively (a complicated case)

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have some serious problems with populating a treeview recursively and I'll apreciate any help.

I have this DataTable:

```
ItemID ItemDesc  Project  Room  Closet  

Item1  Item1Desc Project1 RoomE Closet-7  
Item2  Item2Desc Project1 RoomW Closet8  
Item3  Item3Desc Project1 RoomW Closet8  
Item4  Item4Desc Project1 RoomN Closet2  
Item5  Item5Desc Project1 RoomN Closet9  
Item6  Item6Desc Project2 RoomN Closet2  
Item7  Item7Desc Project2 RoomW Closet9
```

I want to create a TreeView like this:

- Project1

  - RoomE

    - Closet7

      - Item1Desc
  - RoomW

    - Closet8

      - Item2Desc
      - Item3Desc
  - RoomN

    - Closet2

      - Item4Desc
    - Closet9

      - Item5Desc
- Project2

  - RoomN

    - Closet2

      - Item6Desc
  - RoomW

    - Closet2

      - Item7Desc

The way I'm trying to databind the treeview is using

```
private List<treeDataItem> treeData = new List<treeDataItem>();  
mytreeView.DataFieldID = "ID";  
mytreeView.DataFieldParentID = "ParentID";  
mytreeView.DataTextField = "Text";  
mytreeView.DataValueField = "Value";  
mytreeView.DataSource = treeData;  
mytreeView.DataBind();
```

I'm trying to loop thru the DataTable so I can populate treeData but i can't enter the ParentIDs correctly.

Also, to make things complicated the number of fields in the DataTable are variable.
Which means that I can have more fields that identify an item like a "Closet Drawer" and then maybe a "Closet Drawer Section", etc.

So the DataTable can one time be like:

```
ItemID     ItemDescription     Project     Room     Closet     Closet Drawer
```

And another time like:

```
ItemID     ItemDescription     Project     Room     Closet     Closet Drawer     Closet Drawer Section
```

based on user selection.

Here's the treeDataItem class:

```
internal class treeDataItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public Guid Value { get; set; }

    public treeDataItem(int id, int parentId, string text, string value)
    {
        ID = id;
        ParentID = parentId;
        Text = text;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: TreeView in WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: Robert, 
The problem I have is looping thru the Datarows and manage the ParentId in the treedata list. Basically I can't find a way doing this recursively because the number of fields in the datatable can vary. 

Henk,
Is an ASP.NET treeview

Comment: What I don't understand from the statement of the problem is how recursion comes into it. Every recursive algorithm has the same structure. "Am I in the base case? If so, do something easy and return. Otherwise, do something to reduce the problem to a smaller subset of the current problem, and recursively solve the smaller problem".  If you cannot characterize what the base case is, and you cannot characterize how to take a problem and simplify it down to a smaller problem, then recursion isn't the right technique in the first place. So: what's your base case? And what's your recursive step?

Comment: Eric, forget about recursion.

What;s the best way you'll populate the treeview I described with the data as I entered them above?

Comment: Cause not of them solved my problem Guge.

That voting button is not a toy you know.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not familiar with the ASP.NET treeview control, so here's a generic solution.

**DateTable row**

```
class Foo
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

**Tree node**

```
class Node
{
    private readonly string name;
    private readonly Node[] children;

    public Node(string name, Node[] children)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

**Recursive algorithm to group rows into nodes**

```
static IEnumerable<Node> Traverse<T, U>(
    IEnumerable<T> items,
    Func<T, U>[] keySelectors,
    int selectorIndex)
{
    if (selectorIndex < keySelectors.Length)
    {
        foreach (var g in items.GroupBy(keySelectors[selectorIndex]))
        {
            yield return new Node(g.Key.ToString(),
                Traverse(g, keySelectors, selectorIndex + 1).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
var items = new[]
               {
                   new Foo { A = "A1", B = "B1", C = "C1" },
                   new Foo { A = "A1", B = "B1", C = "C2" },
                   new Foo { A = "A1", B = "B2", C = "C1" },
                   new Foo { A = "A1", B = "B2", C = "C2" },
                   new Foo { A = "A2", B = "B1", C = "C1" },
                   new Foo { A = "A2", B = "B1", C = "C2" },
                   new Foo { A = "A2", B = "B2", C = "C1" },
                   new Foo { A = "A2", B = "B2", C = "C2" },
               };

var nodes = Traverse(items, new Func<Foo, string>[]
                            {
                                f => f.A,
                                f => f.B,
                                f => f.C
                            }, 0).ToArray();
```

**Output**

- A1

  - B1

    - C1
    - C2
  - B2

    - C1
    - C2
- A2

  - B1

    - C1
    - C2
  - B2

    - C1
    - C2

Answer (score 0):

I have no expertise in C# but I'd approach a problem like that in two stages:

1. Parse the input into something usable.
2. Then bind the treeview to it.

Your input data is fairly complex so a custom parser to handle all the special situations is well justified.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string[] data = new string[] {
            "Item1 Item1Desc Project1 RoomE Closet-7",
            "Item2 Item2Desc Project1 RoomW Closet8",
            "Item3 Item3Desc Project1 RoomW Closet8",
            "Item4 Item4Desc Project1 RoomN Closet2",
            "Item5 Item5Desc Project1 RoomN Closet9",
            "Item6 Item6Desc Project2 RoomN Closet2",
            "Item7 Item7Desc Project2 RoomW Closet9" };

        foreach (string row in data)
        {
            string[] columns = row.Split(' ');

            TreeNodeCollection treeNodes=treeView1.Nodes;

            for (int col = 2; col < columns.Length; col++)
            {
                string column = columns[col];
                if (!treeNodes.ContainsKey(column))
                {
                    treeNodes.Add(column, column);
                }
                TreeNode tn = treeNodes[column];
                treeNodes = tn.Nodes;
            }
            treeNodes.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", columns[0], columns[1]));
        }
```